# ACCDB + PHP pegar nome das colunas e tabela

Tags: php, sql, microsoft-access

Vou subir arquivos accdb no banco de dados para fazer uma importação de clientes em meu sistema, em um CRM que usava eu conseguia subir esse arquivo e automaticamente já mostrava as colunas para poder estar vinculando com as informações do CRM. Cheguei a conseguir ler os dados do arquivo accdb pelo php e até subir, o que eu precisava é encontrar a tabela que tem dentro desse arquivo e os nome das colunas para poder linkar com os campos necessário, atualmente se eu souber o nome da tabela eu até consigo imprimir na tela os dados do arquivo porem se for um usuario subindo o select já não funcionaria, e consigo dar um select no nome das colunas da tabela?

```
        $pdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=$db; Uid=; Pwd=;");

        $sql = $pdo->prepare("select * from macica");
        $sql->execute();

        while ($linha = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            print_r($linha);

        }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa ter o microsoft Access instalado em seu computador para conseguir abrir um arquivo .accdb, assim poderá ver todas tabelas e consultas do mesmo.